# Convert all exponential numbers to decimal numbers in a file in Linux?

Tags: linux, awk, command-line

I have checked all the previous posts related to this, but I cannot find the way that I wanted to do.

I have a file with some exponential numbers as below. I do not know which columns have exponential numbers.

file1.txt

```
1 499 5e-29 0.33 1.35 46.65
5 999 0.4444 3e-6 0.556 89.444
many more lines
```

I want to convert all the exponential numbers to decimal numbers.

If I want to convert only one number, I could do as below.

```
echo 12.34567E-3 | awk '{printf "%5.10f\n", $1}'
```

But in this way, does anybody know how to do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to apply the same formatting (for example 10 decimal points) for all existing numbers or only for the converted ones?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, thanasisp. No need to apply the same formatting. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop for all fields of each line. Testing for if the field is a numerical value (`$i+0==$i`) and (`&&`) if it contains the character `e` seems good. So we modify only these fields to decimals.

Here using GNU awk `sprintf` function:

```bsh
awk '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i+0 == $i && $i ~ /e/) $i = sprintf("%.10f", $i)
} 1' file
```

- You can use any [format](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html) instead of `.10f` into there.
- `1` at the end means the default action, to `print` the line.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This perfectly worked!!